# One part of layout manager not working and ActionListener not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, layout-manager

I am trying to add the buttons to the mainPanel after i click the button,
currently only appetizer is set,

The second thing is the `GridLayout` on my mainAppPanel is not working, the rows ,vgap and hgap is working but the columns is not.

Please tell me what can be done.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    class sushi implements ActionListener
    {   
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel appPanel;
    private JPanel sideAppPanel;
    private JPanel mainAppPanel;

    private JButton appItemButton1;
    private JButton appItemButton2;
    private JButton appItemButton4;
    private JButton appItemButton5;
    private JButton appItemButton6;
    private JButton appItemButton7;
    private JButton appItemButton8;
    private JButton appItemButton9;
    private JButton appButton;
    private JButton mainButton;
    private JButton sidesButton;
    private JButton dessertButton;
    private JButton drinksButton;
    private JButton totalButton;

    private JLabel blank1;
    private JLabel blank2;
    private JLabel blank3;
    private JLabel blank4;
    private JLabel blank5;
    private JLabel blank6;
    private JLabel blank7;
    private JLabel blank8;
    private JLabel blank9;
    private JLabel blank10;
    private JLabel blank11;
    private JLabel blank12;
    private JLabel blank13;
    private JLabel blank14;
    private JLabel blank15;
    private JLabel blank16;
    private JLabel blank17; 
    private JLabel blank18;
    private JLabel blank19;


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    sushi lol=new sushi();
    }


    public sushi()
    {

//frame settings
frame=new JFrame("sushi master");
frame.setSize(700,700);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocation(300,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(null);

 //sidepanel
sideAppPanel=new JPanel();
sideAppPanel.setSize(100,700);
sideAppPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
sideAppPanel.setLocation(0,0);
sideAppPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(18,0));
frame.add(sideAppPanel);

//items in side panel
 appButton=new JButton("Appetizer");
 mainButton=new JButton("Main course");
 sidesButton=new JButton("Sides");
 drinksButton=new JButton("Drinks");
 totalButton=new JButton("Total");
 blank1=new JLabel(" ");
 blank2=new JLabel(" ");
 blank3=new JLabel(" ");
 blank4=new JLabel(" ");
 blank5=new JLabel("");

 sideAppPanel.add(blank1);
 sideAppPanel.add(appButton);
 sideAppPanel.add(blank2);
 sideAppPanel.add(mainButton);
 sideAppPanel.add(blank3);
 sideAppPanel.add(sidesButton);
 sideAppPanel.add(blank4);
 sideAppPanel.add(drinksButton);
 sideAppPanel.add(blank5);
 sideAppPanel.add(totalButton);

//items in main panel
blank5=new JLabel(" ");
blank6=new JLabel(" ");
blank7=new JLabel(" ");
blank8=new JLabel(" ");
blank9=new JLabel(" ");
blank10=new JLabel(" ");
blank11=new JLabel(" ");
blank12=new JLabel(" ");
blank13=new JLabel(" ");
blank14=new JLabel(" ");
blank15=new JLabel(" ");
blank16=new JLabel(" ");

appItemButton1=new JButton("1");
appItemButton2=new JButton("2");
appItemButton3=new JButton("3");
appItemButton4=new JButton("4");

appItemButton5=new JButton("5");
appItemButton6=new JButton("6");
appItemButton7=new JButton("7");
appItemButton8=new JButton("8");
appItemButton9=new JButton("9");

//adding action listening to side panel buttons
appButton.addActionListener(this);


    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
if(event.getSource()==appButton)
{   
mainAppPanel=new JPanel();
mainAppPanel.setSize(600,700);
mainAppPanel.setLocation(100,0);
mainAppPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
mainAppPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4,20,20));
frame.add(mainAppPanel);
appItemButton1=new JButton("1");
appItemButton2=new JButton("2");
appItemButton3=new JButton("3");
appItemButton4=new JButton("4");

appItemButton5=new JButton("5");
appItemButton6=new JButton("6");
appItemButton7=new JButton("7");
appItemButton8=new JButton("8");
appItemButton9=new JButton("9");

mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton1);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton2);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton3);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton4);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton5);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton6);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton7);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton8);
mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton9);
mainAppPanel.add(blank5);
mainAppPanel.add(blank6);
mainAppPanel.add(blank7);

}
    }   

    }
```

Comment: Define "not working". And where is the ActionListener you mention ?

Comment: Piece of advice, remove this line: `frame.setLayout(null);`. You should never use a `null` LayoutManager. While it is supported, it only leads to problems and never to solutions.

Comment: Start with just a couple of components, a prototype, in which to experiment.

Comment: Please improve the indentation of the code, and see whether you can reproduce your problem with only one or two components. That would make it easier for us to spot potential problems then the current code dump

Comment: thanks to all for replying,
i will try out all the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Points i figured out:

You have not defined

```
private JButton appItemButton3;
```

Your actionlistener works, but you have to validate the changes to the frame.

```
frame.validate();
```

Do you use eclipse or netbeans ide? It helps to format the code and shows some errors or naming conventions like: Classnames uppercase

```
class Sushi implements ActionListener
```

Do not use a null-Layout. You can use Borderlayout to handle all elements.

This should work but i think you should look for some tutorials to learn more about swing:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Sushi implements ActionListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel appPanel;
private JPanel sideAppPanel;
private JPanel mainAppPanel;

private JButton appItemButton1;
private JButton appItemButton2;
private JButton appItemButton3; //added
private JButton appItemButton4;
private JButton appItemButton5;
private JButton appItemButton6;
private JButton appItemButton7;
private JButton appItemButton8;
private JButton appItemButton9;
private JButton appButton;
private JButton mainButton;
private JButton sidesButton;
private JButton dessertButton;
private JButton drinksButton;
private JButton totalButton;

private JLabel blank1;
private JLabel blank2;
private JLabel blank3;
private JLabel blank4;
private JLabel blank5;
private JLabel blank6;
private JLabel blank7;
private JLabel blank8;
private JLabel blank9;
private JLabel blank10;
private JLabel blank11;
private JLabel blank12;
private JLabel blank13;
private JLabel blank14;
private JLabel blank15;
private JLabel blank16;
private JLabel blank17;
private JLabel blank18;
private JLabel blank19;



public static void main(String args[]) {
    Sushi lol = new Sushi();
}

public Sushi() {

    // frame settings
    frame = new JFrame("sushi master");
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocation(300, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    //changed

    // sidepanel
    sideAppPanel = new JPanel();
    sideAppPanel.setSize(100, 700);
    sideAppPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    sideAppPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
    sideAppPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(18, 0));
    frame.add(sideAppPanel, BorderLayout.WEST); //changed

    // items in side panel
    appButton = new JButton("Appetizer");
    mainButton = new JButton("Main course");
    sidesButton = new JButton("Sides");
    drinksButton = new JButton("Drinks");
    totalButton = new JButton("Total");
    blank1 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank2 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank3 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank4 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank5 = new JLabel("");

    sideAppPanel.add(blank1);
    sideAppPanel.add(appButton);
    sideAppPanel.add(blank2);
    sideAppPanel.add(mainButton);
    sideAppPanel.add(blank3);
    sideAppPanel.add(sidesButton);
    sideAppPanel.add(blank4);
    sideAppPanel.add(drinksButton);
    sideAppPanel.add(blank5);
    sideAppPanel.add(totalButton);

    // items in main panel
    blank5 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank6 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank7 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank8 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank9 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank10 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank11 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank12 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank13 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank14 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank15 = new JLabel(" ");
    blank16 = new JLabel(" ");

    appItemButton1 = new JButton("1");
    appItemButton2 = new JButton("2");
    appItemButton3 = new JButton("3");
    appItemButton4 = new JButton("4");

    appItemButton5 = new JButton("5");
    appItemButton6 = new JButton("6");
    appItemButton7 = new JButton("7");
    appItemButton8 = new JButton("8");
    appItemButton9 = new JButton("9");

    // adding action listening to side panel buttons
    appButton.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == appButton) {
        mainAppPanel = new JPanel();
        mainAppPanel.setSize(600, 700);
        mainAppPanel.setLocation(100, 0);
        mainAppPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        mainAppPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4, 20, 20));
        frame.add(mainAppPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);   //changed
        appItemButton1 = new JButton("1");
        appItemButton2 = new JButton("2");
        appItemButton3 = new JButton("3");
        appItemButton4 = new JButton("4");

        appItemButton5 = new JButton("5");
        appItemButton6 = new JButton("6");
        appItemButton7 = new JButton("7");
        appItemButton8 = new JButton("8");
        appItemButton9 = new JButton("9");

        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton1);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton2);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton3);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton4);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton5);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton6);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton7);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton8);
        mainAppPanel.add(appItemButton9);
        mainAppPanel.add(blank5);
        mainAppPanel.add(blank6);
        mainAppPanel.add(blank7);

        frame.validate();   //added
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,
i am new to java and without your help i wont know about frame.validate
i will research on it,